# Advantage in using Java Logger?

Tags: java, logging

I want to log information to a file and want to know is there any advantage in using the Java Logger class versus my own personal method of logging?

I know using a logger I just add my own FileHandler to the logger. My personal method is just using a FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly your logger may be as good, it's pretty easy to put in log levels, filtering, etc.

The problem is when you start to put together code from 10 different groups each with their own logging.  Some use System.out, some use some custom logger, some use log4j, ...

How do you parse or redirect the output?  How do you filter all that output to just show your messages (For instance, filtering options in log4j won't prevent messages being sent straight to System.out).

It's a pretty big bulk change depending on which system you are moving from/to.  Better just to use one very common one from the beginning and hope that it's the one everybody else on the project chooses.

Comment: +1 I would personally vote for JUL.  Definitely avoid the temptation to build your own...

Comment: If you're evil enough and kind of masochistic you can replace the PrintStream for System.out and System.err to filter out things that seem like logging patterns... For me JUL doesn't cut it, but it's as good a start as any.

Comment: @Gressie Actually I did that once--it was really fun actually.  I even gave it the ability to filter it based on module by creating a stack trace for every line printed, looking at the class a couple levels down from the top and filtering based on that--amazingly slow for logging (but honestly not noticeable)--when we shipped it was easy enough to just disable logging altogether or send the raw log to a file instead of stdout because it was all centralized.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is: why would you bother writing your own logger when there are already existing libraries for doing that? Does your logger do something that the others don't? I kind of doubt it.

Standardization is another big issue - see Bill K's answer.

Comment: The answer to your question is because loggers can get complex--and when they get complex and you don't understand them you can lose messages.  The first time you spend a full day trying to figure out why your code isn't running and find that it's because your logger was failing or misconfigured is the last time you trust any new logger.  I often just use System.out because logging has failed for me more than once due to both bugs and misconfiguration--and cost a LOT of very frustrating time.  But overall, your app needs unified logging so eventually you make it work.

Answer (score 1):

For most scenarios, a standard logging framework is the way to go. They are pretty flexible. But using your own implementation can also be a valid option, specially if we are not speaking of traditional logging (global debugging, problems, warning messages) but about specific informational meesages or accounting.

Among other factors, bear in mind that the standarization of logging allows third party libraries to cooperate. For example, if you have a standard web application using (say) Hibernate, and you have configured a standard Java logging lib, then you can not only log from your own code but also tell Hibernate to log debugging info to your log files (not necessarily the same files). That is very useful - almost a must.

If you code your own logging library with a plain FileOutputStream, you must decide -among other things- if you are going to keep the file opened, or reopen-append-close in each write - and you must take of synchronization and related issues. Nothing terribly complicated, though.

Answer (score 0):

The logger gives to ability to define different levels of importance of the logged messages and the ability to use different sink for the output - the console, a file, etc.

Also it's easy to enable or disable only some type of message when using a logger - for example you don't want to see every debug message in production.

Answer (score 0):

A logging framework allows you specify logging levels (e.g. log only critical messages, log only debug messages etc.). It also allows you to log to multiple destinations (e.g. to a file, to syslog etc.) and you can do this even after your application is fully built by just changing a config file and not changing any code. It can also format your logs easily depending on various parameters.

There are numerous other advantages since proper logging is a rather involved problem and these packages have been written to solve them. I think the important question, why would you *not* use them?

Answer (score 0):

Well I would always prefer tested thing and approved by community over something which still need a lot of test. Logger allows you many things which will consume you some time to implement and to test the robustness of your solution. A big plus will be the know-how of the next person who will do something with your code, in case it will be your logger, normally it would take more time to learn how its working out, since there is much more examples and documentation for java.util.logger.

Answer (score 0):

Like all others mention, there are more advantages to using a more common logging system over writing your own. To be honest, the Java util logging api is not nearly as extensive and configurable as other libraries you might find out there on the internet.

Bare in mind that rolling your own always has the disadvantage of being less tested and therefore more prone to break or skip some potentially crucial messages.

Personally I prefer using SLF4J since it allows me to plug in adapters for more commonly used logging frameworks and then let's me pick my own actual logging implementation, this solves most of the problems with different library writers preferring different logging frameworks. And if you consider yourself up for the task you could writer an implementation for SLF4J yourself ;)